# iOS parse issues when retrieving pointer to PFUser

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I have a Follower class where stores all following/follower relations of my app. However, when I was trying to retrieve the pointer of each PFUser, I can't get the attributes of each PFUser. Here is my code

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Follower"];
[query whereKey:@"from" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error)
{
    if (!error)
    {
        for(PFObject *o in objects)
        {
            PFUser *otherUser = (PFUser *)[o objectForKey:@"to"];
            NSLog(@"%@",otherUser);
            NSLog(@"%@",otherUser.username);

            NSString *nickName = otherUser[@"nickName"];
            cell.friendNameLabel.text = nickName;
            NSLog(@"%@", otherUser[@"nickName"]);
            //cell.friendUsrnameLabel.text = otherUser.username;
            PFFile *imgFile = otherUser[@"profilePhoto"];
            profileView.file = imgFile;
            [profileView loadInBackground];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"error");
    }

}];
```

when I tried to print every user, here is what i got from the console:

```
<PFUser: 0x7fc102ec9f70, objectId: GiOIGiNHjK, localId: (null)> {
}
```

so it didn't find the attributes of each user. Anyone knows the solution? Thanks.[image: the join table i used in the Follower class]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add this line before executing the query.

```
[query includeKey:@"to"];
```

Comment: oh well that bloody works! thx man! But the the iOS guide on parse.com doesn't have this line. Any thoughts? Maybe this is a silly question, but I just started with parse last month...

Comment: Here Parse explaining that. http://blog.parse.com/announcements/queries-for-relational-data/